# No consigo iterar los textos con las primeras 500 Lineas

Tags: python

No consigo la forma de iterar el texto para sacar las 500 primeras lineas de todos los ficheros de ese directorio y sacarlas en otro texto, a ver si me podeis echar un cable por que estoy bastante atascad.

```
os.chdir("English/")
for file in glob.glob("*.srt"):
    print(file)


    f = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig')
    for lines in f:
        save = f.readlines()[:500]
        print(lines)

        f.close()

        guardar = translator.translate(text=save, dest='es', src='en')
```

Siempre me explota aqui

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

en la ultima linea.

Comment: Seguro que todos tienen al menos 500 líneas? Y como consejo, usar readlines es ineficiente.

Comment: Si todos son ficheros de mas de 500 lineas, que es mas recomendable entonces realizar para la lectura de lineas?

Comment: la ultima linea donde hago el text=save ese save que tengoo es donde me explota la iteracion.

Comment: ¿`translator` de que es instancia? ¿de que módulo sale? ¿`translate`?, ¿`googletrans`?, ¿otro?.

Comment: de googletrans es la instancia

Comment: Vale, ¿la idea seria traducir linea a linea y todas al mismo fichero de salida o las 500 de cada a uno distinto?

Comment: la idea es traducir las 500 lineas de cada archivo ya que si el archivo es muy grande no se te permite googletrans, entonce seria hacerlo como en tramos para sacar el fichero final.

Comment: Vale, pero entonces ¿cada fichero querrías traducirlo entero? Si es así, deberías fragmentar el fichero y traducirlo a trozos y guardarlo traducido, luego pasar al siguiente y así, no leer las primeras 500 de todos. ¿O me estoy perdiendo?

Comment: Si asi es exactamente FJSevilla, pero tengo un cacao ya con los bucles, en este ultimo caso lo que estaba era recorriendo las 500 primeras lineas de todos, guardo y vuelve a recorrer las siguientes lineas de todos y las añado a los ficheros ya creado anteriormente.

Answer (score 0):

Hay una [buena discusión](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246260/python-readlines-usage-and-efficient-practice-for-reading) en SO original sobre la eficiencia de `readlines()`. Básicamente, el lío está en que va a leer todo el archivo antes de iterar entre las líneas. Cargas en memoria todo el archivo antes de comenzar a recorrerlo.

Para evitar semejante cosa, uno puede definir el buffer asignado al readlines

```
with open('foo') as f:
    while True:
        lines = f.readlines(8192)
        if not lines:
            break
        for line in lines:
            pass
```

o iterar de forma mucho más sencilla:

```
with open('foo') as f:
    for line in f:
        pass
```

Ya ahí deberías poder guardar en el otro archivo lo que intentas guardar.

Sobre tu error, posiblemente la doble iteración

```
...
 f = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') 
    for lines in f:   # primera iteracion línea a línea
        save = f.readlines()[:500]   #segunda iteracion
...
```

está haciendo que el cierre del archivo genere líos al seguir iterando y el readlines falle porque line es nulo. Simplifica la iteración para evitar este problema